# Comboboxcolumn datagridview c# sql server

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en c# y sql server. Al seleccionar un item de un comboboxcolumn me debe traer la descripción y precio desde la base de datos, si lo hace pero me marca el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo estos eventos

```
private void dgtDVenta_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            dgvCombo = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;

            if (dgvCombo != null)
            {
                dgvCombo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dgtDVenta_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
        }
 private void dgtDVenta_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvCombo != null)
                dgvCombo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(dgtDVenta_SelectedIndexChanged);

        }

private void dgtDVenta_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
            cadena = "Server= " + serverName + ";Database= " + dataBase + " ;Trusted_Connection=True";
            string des;
            string precio;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cadena))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string sql = @"SELECT Descripcion_Prod, Precio FROM Producto WHERE IdProducto = @IdProducto";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdProducto", combo.Text);
                adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                tabla = new DataTable();
                adaptador.Fill(tabla);
                //des = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                des = tabla.Rows[0]["Descripcion_Prod"].ToString();
                precio = tabla.Rows[0]["Precio"].ToString();
            }

            DataGridViewRow row = dgtDVenta.CurrentRow;
            row.Cells["Descripcion"].Value = des;
            row.Cells["Precio"].Value = precio;


        }
```

Comment: Has comprobado que los nombres de las columnas del datagridview sean correctos? Se llaman `Descripción` y `Precio`?

Comment: El error puede ser porque `tabla` no tiene filas y en ese código asume que hay datos retornados de la consulta.